# Which Hashfunction to choose for parallel insertion of a set of values?

Tags: parallel-processing, hashmap

I have a hashtable T of size w*h with a bucket per entry for storing values mapped to the same hash.

Now I want to insert a set of values G. 
each value in G contains of a position tuple (x,y) and a certain payload p.

The hash function uses the position tuple of the value as parameter: H(x,y).
G is essentially a grid with each position storing a payload p.

To insert all values from G into T in parallel without synchronization, H should guarantee different hashs for all values in G.

The width of G is smaller than w and its height is smaller than h, so

```
H(x,y) = mod y * w + mod x
```

would be suitable.

However, this simple modulo hash function is only sufficient for [uniformly distributed data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hashing_uniformly_distributed_data).

In [literature](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2508363.2508374), a better suited (at least for my application) hash function is proposed:

```
H(x,y) = (x*p xor y*q) mod(w*h)
```

where p and q are large prime numbers.
But I'm unsure how to check if all values of the grid would be mapped to different hashs.

Does anyone know how to prove that (if this is the case) or does anyone know a suited hash function?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that you'll have to pre-allocate your hash table to the maximum size. Otherwise, resizing on one thread while adding on another will cause you grief.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jim. My hash table is of fixed size. Resizing is indeed a problem. Also dealing with bucket overflows is an issue which can be solved using other collision resolving strategies which must be executed sequentially.